# reading all attributes of xml elements at once

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have xml file as below

```
<dashboard  DASHBOARD_ID="1" DASHBOARD_IMAGE="" DASHBOARD_NAME="TestDashboard">
<linkedpages>
<pages page_id=1212 pagename=""/>
<report reportid=212 reportname=""/>
</linkedpages>
```

my need is that I should import these tag attribute velues int o respective table say page table, report table, dashborad table and so on.

I am get the elements and their attributes by

```
String attribute = child.getAttribute("report_id");
```

but I need to write n number of such line, and its not generic, i can have variable length of attributes.
So i need to be able to read all attributes of each tag.

How can this be done Please help, Any idea of doing this is appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method : [getAttributes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadataNode.html)

And an example:

```
List<String> attributNames = new ArrayList<String>();
if(child.getAttributes() != null){
    for (int i = 0; i < child.getAttributes().getLength(); i++) {
        attributNames.add(child.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] attributes = new String[child.getAttributes().getLength()];
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        attributes[i] = child.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue();
    }
```

Comment: thanx for the instant reply both the solutions work.